# How to allocate a bitmap in custom surfaceview after onMeasure?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-bitmap

I have a custom SurfaceView, the init function loads all Bitmaps and it's called from the constructor, but I want resize a Bitmap and I can do this only after onMeasure and before onDraw.This is my OnMeasure method inside my custom SurfaceView:

```
@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    measuredHeight = MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec);
    measuredWidth = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);
    scrollableBg = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(srcScrollableBg, measuredWidth, measuredHeight, true);
    super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
}
```

the IDE says "Avoid object allocations during draw/layout operations (preallocate and reuse instead)" for the scrollableBg allocating, but I can't do this in the init because I haven't the measuredWidth and the measuredHeight...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider using `onLayout`:

> protected void onLayout (boolean changed, int left, int top, int
>   right, int bottom)
>
> Added in API level 1 Called from layout when this view should assign a
>   size and position to each of its children. Derived classes with
>   children should override this method and call layout on each of their
>   children.

It’s called after `onMeasure`. A good practice could be to allocate your object only when `changed == true`: you will get the same warning from the IDE, but this way you can safely ignore it.

```
@Override
protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int left, int top, int right, int bottom) {
    if (changed) {
        // allocate bitmap
        // get width with right - left
        // get height with bottom - top
    }
    super.onLayout(changed, left, top, right, bottom);
}
```